# Wildcard error while using ansible command line

Tags: ansible

```
[root@toure1~]# ansible -i ansi all -a  'df -Ph | grep -i overf'
slave62 | FAILED | rc=1 >>
df: `|': No such file or directory
df: `grep': No such file or directory
df: `overf': No such file or directory
df: no file systems processed

[root@toure1~]# ansible -i ansi all -a  "cat /etc/*release"
slave61 | FAILED | rc=1 >>
cat: /etc/*release: No such file or directory
```

What can be done to resolve the error.
Is there a way to by pass wildcard

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
ansible -i ansi all -m shell -a "cat /etc/*release"
```